# Don't load plugin DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to order the columns of table and I use DataTables plugin:

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

I follow this tutorial but I think that in my code the plugin it doesn't load.
This is my code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dataTables.numericComma.js"></script>
</head>

<table id="tab">...
</table>

<script...>
    alert("STAR");
    var oTable = $('#tab').dataTable();
    alet("END");
</script>
```

the problem is the that the program prints "START" but it doesn't print "END" so I think this is a problem of plugin's load. Anyone can help me?

Comment: did you try `alert` instead of `alet`? ;-)

Comment: You need to load jQuery library as well, please read [DataTables Installation](http://datatables.net/manual/installation) chapter.

Comment: it's alert sorry....I Wrong to paste!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure HTML code and datatables files are allocated at the same folder level

Comment: Not sure who gave you a minus for this, but it could be the case, so I have upvoted.